# Do something when Promise outside then finished

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

Here is the code.

```
function getPromise():Promise<any> {
    let p = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        //some logical
        resolve(data);
    });
    p.finally(()=>{ 
        //I want do something when outside then finished! 
        console.log("finally hit");
    });
    return p;
}

function doPromise():void {
    a.getPromise().then(data => { console.log("then hit"); });
}
```

But the finally runs before then. So how can I do something after outside then.

I do not want to add finally after then, because the promise called many places. so I want do it in one place.

Comment: Shouldn't you be returning the result of `p.finally(...)`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally#return_value

Comment: @AluanHaddad I tried, return p.finally the calling order is resolve->finally->then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is retrun a callback which you can use later on like this:

```
type GetPromise = {
  p: Promise<any>;
  finalCallback: () => void;
}
function getPromise():GetPromise {
  let p = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
      //some logical
      resolve(data);
  });
  finalCallback(()=>{ 
      //I want do something when outside then finished! 
      console.log("finally hit");
  });
  return {p, finalCallback};
}

function doPromise():void {
  const {p: promise, finalCallback} = getPromise()
  promise().then(data => { 
    console.log("then hit");  
    finalCallback();
  });
}
```

Comment: I don't want the caller to execute it. I want to execute it auto. But it's a smart way to achieve it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can incorporate callback into `getPromise`?

```js
function getPromise(callback):Promise<any> {
    let p = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        //some logical
        resolve(data);
    });
    p.then(callback)
    p.finally(()=>{ 
        //I want do something when outside then finished! 
        console.log("finally hit");
    });
    return p;
}

function doPromise():void {
    getPromise(data => { console.log("then hit"); });
}
```

Comment: yeah, but I think there is no need to return Promise anymore. If method getPromise with a then, It will be called after the finally.

Comment: @oudi Sometimes you want to continue work after promise, so you must return it

Answer (score 1):

Your `getPromise()` its a Promise itself, so your `.then()` will run only after it concludes, in this case, after the `.finally()`.

You can put the `.then()` inside of `getPromise()` or move the `.finally()` to the outside after the `.then()`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. `promise.then()` returns a new promise, the original `promise` cannot get a reference for that (may be multiple and may be none, it's like a tree).

Instead you can provide `console.log("then hit")` to `getPromise()` as a callback, which is used during create the promise.

```js
function getPromise(cb) {
    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //some logical
        resolve();
    });
    p.then(cb).finally(()=>{ 
        //I want do something when outside then finished! 
        console.log("finally hit");
    });
    return p;
}
function doPromise() {
    getPromise(data => { console.log("then hit"); });
}

doPromise()
```